# How to put all the images in line?

Tags: html, css

How to make all the images to fall in line? Nothing seems to work...

Is it about the size of the photos? Not used the classes properly?

```css
.fac {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.col {
  flex-basis: 31%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  text-align: center;
}

.col img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: -4px;
}

.col p {
  padding: 0;
}

.col h3 {
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}

.col p {
  padding: 0;
}

.col h3 {
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<section class="fac">
  <h1>Linia de productie sau ceva</h1>
  <p>Yes, I guess?</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <img src="../photos/stc.jpg">
      <h3>yuo gen roadmap</h3>
      <p>ceva descriere</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <img src="../photos/meatthemeat.jpg">
      <h3>Bsalasaaa da</h3>
      <p>dfasd</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <img src="../photos/bbc.jpg">
      <h3>aasdasa da</h3>
      <p>adsfd</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because you have use row for each img, you can edit code and set display flex for row tag like this
HTML :

```
    <section class="fac">
     <h1>Linia de productie sau ceva</h1>
     <p>Yes, I guess?</p>
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col">
         <img src="../photos/stc.jpg">
         <h3>yuo gen roadmap</h3>
         <p>ceva descriere</p>
       </div>
       <div class="col">
         <img src="../photos/stc.jpg">
         <h3>Bsalasaaa da</h3>
         <p>dfasd</p>
       </div>
       <div class="col">
         <img src="../photos/stc.jpg">
         <h3>aasdasa da</h3>
         <p>adsfd</p>
       </div>
     </div>
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
.row{
  display : flex;
  justify-content : space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `display: flex;` to `.col` class and it will work.